# Why decimal.Decimal doesn't support arithmetic operations with float-data type?

Tags: python

I am working on some scripts that handle calculation with the need of maintaining high accuracy of the results so I started using decimal.Decimal instead of built-in float.

I know it doesn't work with float-type values and it returns TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'
What I need to know exactly is why it doesn't support this type of operations with float.

Sample:

```
from decimal import Decimal

expr_= 1.2+Decimal('1')
```

As this seems logic for me when I try to add str to float to get this type of error but not while trying to calculate two numeric values.

While I can easily do the same thing using SymPy Float data-type without facing any issues. Ex:

```
from decimal import Decimal
from sympy import Float
expr_=Decimal('1.6')+Float(1.2)
```

Comment: Probably because it’s unclear whether the result would be a float or a Decimal, and what precision it would have.

Comment: I edited the details of the question with an example where Python handheld this a similar situation without returning any issues.

Comment: I guess it's a precaution. If you need super-high precision, accidentally adding a regular float might be like adding "well, dunno, about a million or so" to a number accurate to 10 places after the decimal. If you _really_ want this, you can just convert the `float` to `Decimal` before adding.

Comment: ... and while _some_ numbers can be accurately represented as `float`, it would be impossible to tell whether your number is one of those, or just got rounded to one of those.

Comment: SymPy isn’t part of Python and it’s free to make different choices about its addition operator (which `Decimal('1.6')+Float(1.2)` will defer to).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[PEP 327 -- Decimal Data Type](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0327/) explains:

> Aahz is strongly opposed to interact with float, suggesting an explicit conversion:
>
> > The problem is that Decimal is capable of greater precision, accuracy, and range than float.
>
> The example of the valid python expression, `35 + 1.1`, seems to suggest that
>     `Decimal(35) + 1.1` should also be valid. However, a closer look shows that it
>     only demonstrates the feasibility of integer to floating point
>     conversions. Hence, the correct analog for decimal floating point is 35 +
>     Decimal(1.1). Both coercions, int-to-float and int-to-Decimal, can be done
>     without incurring representation error.
>
> The question of how to coerce between binary and decimal floating point is
>     more complex. I proposed allowing the interaction with float, making an exact
>     conversion and raising ValueError if exceeds the precision in the current
>     context (this is maybe too tricky, because for example with a precision of 9,
>     Decimal(35) + 1.2 is OK but Decimal(35) + 1.1 raises an error).
>
> This resulted to be too tricky. So tricky, that c.l.p agreed to raise TypeError in this case: you could not mix Decimal and float.

This is the python developer's [mailing list discussion](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-October/039755.html) on the subject. For the full thread, see the [2003-10 archive](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-October/subject.html) and search for "Decimal".

So in the end, the ["Explicit is better than implicit"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) philosophy won out.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful.